# Why does my code work when use std::io::Write is in my main but not when it's in my lib

Tags: rust, macros, stdout, flush

I have two files I'm working with, main.rs and lib.rs.

main.rs:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Write; //My library depends on this line :(

use input_macro_attempt::input;

fn main() {
    let x = input!("Enter a variable: ");

    println!("The variable is: {}", x);

}
```

lib.rs:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Write; //This one is irrelevant?

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! input{
    ($a:expr) =>{
       {
        
        print!("{}", $a);
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        input
       }
    };

   (_) =>{{
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        
        input
        }
    };


}
```

I've experimented but when I remove the use "std::io::Write" from main.rs my code breaks but **why?**

I didn't like how the output came out with println! so I switched to print! and manually flushed it so that you could put the input on the same line as the message.

Example: Enter the input: *Your input*

I add it to my `lib.rs` and it doesn't make a difference, it only works if my `main.rs` has it and I'm a little frustrated because in my lib it ignores the whole use term.

Comment: This might be because the macro doesn't actually compile the code it generates, it just generates code that gets compiled in the context in which the macro is used.

Comment: While I get that having to wait to post a question can be frustrating to avoid confusion on all ends you should refrain from asking 2 questions in the same Stack Overflow question unless they're very tigthly related, I've removed the second question from this post to make it less confusing for future viewers.

Comment: @cafce25 Thank you, I wouldn't want to confuse anyone in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust as in other languages macro expansion is just a sort of text replacement mechanism, (well, ok Rust also checks token types etc but for your question we can ignore that) so you can think of `input!("Enter a variable: ")` as being replaced with the contents of the macro at the call site.
If you want to use an include, you have to include it within the macro itself, not the module it's defined in.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! input {
    ($a:expr) => {{
        use ::std::io::Write;

        print!("{}", $a);
        ::std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        let mut input = String::new();
        ::std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        input
    }};

    (_) => {{
        use ::std::io::Write;

        let mut input = String::new();
        ::std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

        input
    }};
}
```

I use `::` in front of the `use` and other `std` elements to guarantee I'm not accidentially including a submodule `std` of the call site.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me, I don't mean to disturb you but could you help me trim the whitespace of the input?

Comment: Use [`.trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim).

Comment: I keep getting errors about the borrowed value not living long enough, so I can't get it to work.

Comment: See if you can't [find](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+trim+borrowed) a solution in another question.